# MYSQL Search on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose that I do not have a certain id in mysql database. I am using rails, so the following code that I am using to query the database is the following...

`@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])`

How do I raise an exception of the ID does not exist? Please let me know :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `find` on an ActiveRecord model it will automatically raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception if the ID passed doesn't correspond to an existing record in the database. You can recover from this, but make sure you don't rely on this as expected flow (i.e. you don't want to do the above routine in a check on every page load, even when you don't know if `params[:id]` is even set).

```
def show
  @customer = Customer.find params[:id]
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to customers_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the id does not exist your @customer will be nil.

```
raise Exception.new "SomeText" if @customer.nil?
```